# Change Material Properties of Multiple Materials

Tags: python, texturing, materials, scripting, properties

I'm importing hundreds of different textures into Blender and I want to change the blend mode on all of them from Alpha Blend to Opaque. I understand I will need to run a python command, however the ones I have tried do not work. Help would be appreciated

Edit: here are 2 of the scripts I have tried running--

```
for material in bpy.data.materials:
        material.blend_method = 'OPAQUE'
```

the first one gives me this error:

```
  File "<blender_console>", line 4
    for material in bpy.data.materials:
IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'for' statement on line 3
```

Here's the 2nd one that I tried

```
object = bpy.context.active_object
for slot in object.material_slots:
    if slot.material:
        slot.material.blend_method = 'OPAQUE'
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Please provide the script that didn't work.

Comment: @RumenBelev I have posted the scripts, although it seems like the first one should work. I'm not sure why it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indentation is important when interpreting the script.
You have two tabs on the first script and it is supposed to be a single tab indentation. Also Blender developers recommend using 4 spaces as indentation instead of tabs (although both variants work):
Try copying and running the script bellow:

```
import bpy
for material in bpy.data.materials:
    material.blend_method = 'OPAQUE'
```

The second script also works. Make sure to include the line

**import bpy**

at the beginning of each script.

```
import bpy
object = bpy.context.active_object
for slot in object.material_slots:
    if slot.material:
        slot.material.blend_method = 'OPAQUE'
```

Link to Best Practice
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_best_practice.html

Comment: This works! Thank you so much for your help